# How to run jetty:run-exploded in maven but prevent from assembling war again?

Tags: java, maven-2, jetty

We are using the maven jetty plug-in to run exploded wars.

We have a script that copies certain configuration files to the directory which is used by maven to assemble the war (basically spring configuration + `web.xml` for stand-alone test environment).

The problem is that it seems the webapp is being built again before jetty:run-exploded is called which replaces our custom config files we copied in. Strangely enough this is only affecting people on Windows and not the Ubuntu users.

Anyone know of a way to run the `jetty:run-exploded` task but prevent Maven from building anything before doing it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using executions?  http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html

I am not sure if they would work, but if it's possible, I think that is how it would be configured.

Answer (score 0):

The run:exploded goal documentation says that it will run package which is what you are seeing.

"We have a script that copies certain configuration files..."

You might want to find out what maven "profile"s are instead. This is the real problem here.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the `deploy-war` goal instead of `exploded`, as per http://eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-maven-plugin.html#deploy-war-running-pre-assembled-war:

> This is basically the same as jetty:run-war, but without assembling the WAR of the current module - you can nominate the location of any war to run. Unlike run-war, the phase in which this plugin executes is not bound to the "package" phase - you may bind it to any phase to use it.